# Can't share PDF file with WhatsApp or email (Only IOS)

Tags: ios, react-native

I use `react-native-share` package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share

i try to share base64 in this way:

```
import Share from 'react-native-share'
//
const base64File = //base64 file
const pdf = "data:application/pdf;base64," + base64File
const options = { title: 'Share via', url: pdf };
Share.open(options)
```

It works in `android` but not in `IOS`, when i try to share `tiff` file it works in `IOS` but not `pdf`

When i try this informs me - this file cannot be shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
import Share from 'react-native-share'
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob'
//
const base64File = //base64 file
const pdf = "data:application/pdf;base64," + base64File
let filePath = '';
const path = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir + '/someFileName.pdf';
const configOptions = { fileCache: true, path };
let fullPath = await RNFetchBlob.config(configOptions).fetch('GET', encodeURI(fileUrl))
filePath = fullPath.path();
let options = {
    title: 'Share via'
    type: type,
    url: filePath // (Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'file://' + filePath)
};
Share.open(options)
```

Comment: What is `fileUrl` in the full path?

Comment: @ASN I don't remember clearly but i this URL of some pdf like - 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf' 
but again it's was before a year so...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in react native share. Then i use [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) for sharing my pdf file

```
Share.open({
            title: "Pdf file",
            message: "my Text:",
            url: "file:///storage/../../test.pdf",
            subject: "PDF",
        })
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you but its not work for me, can you tell me your `react-native` and `react-native-share` versions

Comment: Yes sure, react-native version:- "0.58.4" and my react-native-share version:- "1.1.3"

Comment: what's exactly the issue you are facing. Can you please elaborate on this

Comment: when i try to share pdf with whatsapp or gmail i get popup with error 'cannot sharing item...', if i try sharing with mailto for example it work fine

Comment: This link  "https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share#share-base-64-file" might be helpful for you